# How to Click All Inputs with the Same Class on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, click

I have a table with multiple rows (hundreds) on my web page. Each table row has an input with the class name of `act_inv`. I am trying to get JavaScript/JQuery to click each input with the class name of `act_inv`. Is this possible? And if so, how may I do this?

The code I am using so far (which does not work) is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   document.onload = function() {
    $('.act_inv').each(function(){
         $(this).trigger('click');
        if ( $(this).trigger('click')) {
            alert("hi");
        }
    });  
   }
});
```

An example of my inputs:

```
<input class="act_inv" type="text">
<input class="act_inv" type="text">
<input class="act_inv" type="text">
```

Comment: `$(".act_inv").click()` doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't seem so. I am using an alert (see my updated question) in the code to see if it clicks, and no alerts are appearing.

Comment: you have other problems that keep the alert from showing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `document.onload`, and simply do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.act_inv').click();
});
```

This assumes a `click()` handler has already been created for that class.

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.act_inv').click(function() {
    $(this).val('clicked');
  });
  
  $('.act_inv').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="act_inv" type="text">
<input class="act_inv" type="text">
<input class="act_inv" type="text">
```

Comment: I have a click handler underneath the code, which is  `$(".act_inv").focusout(function() { alert("Test"); });`; the alert is not showing when I refresh the page.

Comment: If there's no `click()` handler, then nothing would happen.  What would you like to happen?

Comment: @Kelsey, assign them before hand like `$(element).click(function(){...});` before hand meaning before the `$(document).ready`

Comment: It can be defined within `$(document).ready()`, as long as it's defined before the call to `$('.act_inv').click();`.  See my Snippet for an example `click` handler, which sets the value of each clicked `input` to "clicked."

Comment: Works now, thanks. I had my handler after the call to click, instead of before.

Comment: Yep, that would cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned in your question that each row has an **input**, you can do something like this. It works because I use it in my application where there are 300 fields.

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
           $(this).click();
     });
```